# What's the difference between const int& and int&

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I got 3 questions.

1.what is the difference between the flowing 2 codes?

```
//why no errors during compiling as flowing
const int& get3() {
    return 3;
}
```

and

```
//get a compiler error, says: 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'
//and that's understandable
int& get3() {
    return 3;
}
```

2.Why the first one is OK to compile?

3.And when i run the first one, i got the strange result:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXAgd.png)

That's why?

I'll appreciate it very much if anyone can give me some tips.

Comment: About the compiler error: What do you think `get3() = 4;` would do (if the compiler wouldn't complain)?

Comment: Please paste your code as code, not as an image.

Comment: I suggest reading https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness which saved my life.

Answer (score 3):

With `int& get3()` you can do, for example, `get3() = 5`.

This will set the value of the variable whose reference is returned by function `get3` to `5`.

Since `3` is a constant value with no address to be used as reference, you get a compilation error.

Such functions typically return a reference to a class member variable.

Answer (score 1):

2. The first one is actually *not* OK, even though it compiles. It returns a reference to a local temporary which is undefined behavior (because that temporary gets destroyed after function exits, so you get a dangling reference). The compiler should have already told you about this by issuing a warning.

   Basically it's equivalent to the following:

   ```
   const int& get3() {
       const int& x = 3; // bind const reference to a temporary, OK
       return x; // return a reference to a temporary, UB
   }
   ```

   And this also answers your third question:
3. Because you have UB in your code.

I'd also recommend to read [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/3959454).

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you say in "2." and why the second function got a compiler error.  Sorry for not describing my question clear, I'm wondering why the first function returned "const int&" complies by return a constant int 3?

Comment: @KangYin again, this particular code contains undefined behavior and the function can return anything, including `3`.